# White screen after redirecting to another url. Deployed with Heroku, developed with React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, heroku, react-hooks, heroku-cli

everyone. I'm having a problem viewing a page from Heroku. The following: I have an application where a user has to register (email, password). An email will then be sent from Spring Boot to his email address with a verification link in it. If the user clicks on this, he will be redirected to a confirmation page (also in heroku). So far so good. The problem now is that I don't see anything on the confirmation page. I get the following error in the debugger:

> main.f0ce501a.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at
> main.f0ce501a.js:1:1) manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1,
> syntax error.

The URL on which the redirect takes place looks like this:

> https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/registrierung/631868ce8aa8d25f58f07668.

However, I am trying to redirect to a URL like this:

> https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/ThankYou

so I don't get any problem at all and the page loads without a problem. I think it has something to do with the UserID in the URL, but I have no idea why

My App.js for forwarding:

```
<Route path="/registrierung/:id" element={<Registrierung />} />
```

This is what my React component looks like, in which I need the UserId from the URL

```
export default function Registrierung() {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const path = useLocation().pathname.split("/")[2];

useEffect(() => {
const registrierungAbgschlossen = async () => {
  await axiosInstance
    .put(`/benutzer/update/${path}`, {
      emailBestaetig: true,
      emailBestaetigtAm: new Date(),
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate("/Login");
      }, 3000);
    });
};
registrierungAbgschlossen();
}, [path]);

 return (
<Box sx={{ p: 1, mt: 5 }}>
  <Typography variant="h6" align="center">
    Vielen Dank für Ihre Registrierung. Sie werden nach 3 Sekunden
    automatisch weitergeleitet
  </Typography>
</Box>
  );
}
```

And this is the URL from inside Spring Boot

> String url = "https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/registrierung/"+userId;

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're getting an HTML network error. Check the network panel.

Comment: Thanks. But no, not a single error in the network tab. The strange thing is that everything works under localhost.

Comment: Please link to the app or a reproduction of the issue.